# When I need to create new table and connect it using foreign key to other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
idFilmAward   Name
--------------------------------
1             Academy Awards
2             Saturn Award
..            ...
```

Lets say I also have this table:

```
###############
###First Way###
###############
idAward       Name            idFilmAward
------------------------------------------
1             Best Director   1
2             Best Director   2
..            ....            ..
100           Best Actor      1
```

Lets say in "First Way" the "Best Director" repeated only two times so it mean I don't need to use "Second Way":

```
################
###Second Way###
################
idAward       idAwardName       idFilmAward
------------------------------------------
1             1                 1
2             1                 2
..            ....              ..
100           2                 1

idAwardName   Name              idAward
-------------------------------------------
1             Best Director     1
2             Best Actor        2
...           ...               ...
```

But lets say "Best Director" repeated 100 times, then I need to do use "Second Way", right? My question is how many repeats it's ok to have so to use "First Way" and after how many repeats I should use "Second Way"?

Comment: This is completely subjective, and we don't know enough about the needs of this data to answer.  If the data needs to be completely normalized, then you don't want any "repeats."  If the data needs to be de-normalized for various optimizations then "repeats" are ok and expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) says that you should always use second way.

You should avoid repeating the same data in different rows in a "perfect" relational database design. In this way, if you want to change the name of the award from "Best Director" to "Best Senior Director" you should update many rows (in the first way) and just one row (in the second way).

But in Data warehouse design, where you use snowflake design, the first is the best way.

Comment: Now that you mentioned that one award can change name I understood that I need to use first way because if one change it doesn't mean that all "Best Director" should be renamed to "Best Senior Director". Thank you very much and I thank the other guys too you all helped me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of how many times it repeats. The database has to be normalized (third normal form at least). So "if it repeats even once" or better "could repeat" in your case use a separate table. (This is not a notion)

One of the isolated cases when you do not want a normalized database is when using performance critical operations on a large amount of data in which case a de-normalized database would achieve faster(better) results.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use second way any time when the repeat situation can happen. Because it's looks like a dictionary - it is 3rd normal form of database normalizing

Answer (score 1):

My gut response is that this is premature optimization. At the moment, you're probably not using this database enough that it matters how you store the data (it won't have a big impact on your servers etc), and the database itself won't stop you having as many repeats as you like.

That said, I would have the following:

- An awardgivers table with an id and name
- An awards table with an id, an awardgiver_id (that references AcademyAwards etc) and a name
- An award_recipient table with an award_id and a film_id.

The reason for this is that not all ceremonies have the same list of awards. And because it makes logical sense to me to separate out the different awards and their names from the different ceremonies.